# padding style applying to <td /> doesn't work on IE7

Tags: html, css

It seems that **padding** style applying to `<td />` doesn't work on IE7 in my computer, but is okay on FireFox3.5.

Is this a correct behavior? Or I get wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`<td />` is not accepted well by browsers. I've run into various problems with this approach.

Make it `<td></td>`.